# What does the second argument of the Session.pop method do in Python Flask?

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm working through the Flask tutorial and would just like to clarify exactly what the .pop attr of the session object does and why it would take a 'None' parameter.

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to [Flask's API](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/) their `Session` class is a wrapper around a python `Dict`. According to the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) for `dict.pop()`:

> `pop(key[, default])`
>
> If `key` is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value, else return `default`. If `default` is not given and `key` is not in the dictionary, a `KeyError` is raised.

In this case the tutorial asks you to pass in `None` as the `default` value.

Comment: The passing of the default value in the tutorial thus prevents the `KeyError` exception being raised in case someone who is not logged in would access `/logout` (key `logged_in` would not be present in the session then).