# How to delete key from flask session dictionary?

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-session

I want to delete a key from a flask session dictionary like this:

```
del session["host"]
```

The host key gets deleted (I tested this by printing), but when the page gets redirected, if reappears (I did this by deleting it and then printing it in another request). How can I fix this? If you want me to, I will post the full code. (I am using the same tab in an incognito browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the dictionary outside of a function that has the `app.route()` decorator. Make sure you modify it inside of a function with the decorator.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try to do is do the following:

```
session.pop("host",None)
```

I got this answer from [What does the second argument of the Session.pop method do in Python Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115662/what-does-the-second-argument-of-the-session-pop-method-do-in-python-flask)